Factory conveyer belt
I am doing a project for the university, I want to make a conveyor belt for a recycling company, but it has been difficult for me to move the pieces of plastic along the belt, could you help me?
Something similar to this video:
https://youtube.com/shorts/DgB-i1p_3Ug?si=Z3f3RqPOY2KwfLfk

I want the parts to fall from the hopper and move along the conveyor belt.


File


hello please share your file so that we can see what the problem is?

Hello, please again share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

How are we supposed to solve the problem when we do not see any settings or have a file to inspect? We can only see that the object "Plane.009" is set to be a passive rigid body. But what is it? Is anything moving there to transport the pieces? There is no animation data visible. Is this "Plane.009" supposed to be moving? If so, you have to enable the Animated checkbox if you want it to interact with other rigid bodies.



You could try to add rigid body physics to every plastic (as convex hull, active).
Set a low bouncyness and not very high friction (because it might get stuck). Make the conveyour a passive rigid body as well (low bouncyness high friction) and just animate the conveyor.

It would need to be a step by step process... you would need first to block the bottom of the funnel, let the plastics fall inside (because right now they're too close and they will explode away when you add ridig body to them), after they fall inside, you then bake them and get that final position as starting position for a new animation, now with the funnel unblocked. And you will need to create invisible walls on the conveyour because it doesn't transfer speed to the plastics.
